# Copying Only Specific Cells in Excel

Tags: excel

Say I have a column of names, some of which have a certain word 'ABCD' in the name (or perhaps two words).  Suppose that I want to sort by these words?  What would be the easiest way to go about doing this so that an adjacent column also is rearranged along with the selected entries (essentially I want to bunch all of these together).  Thanks!

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand your questiong completely but try this.

Go to Data and then Filter and you should notice that your header row now has dropdown arrows(assuming you have a header row). Simply click on whichever row you want to sort by and type in the string you want to find. Then you can group those however you want using the group tool.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a new column, in which the contents are a formula that matches the words you want to sort by. Then, sortby that column